Scripting automated login to Gmail but it doesn't work
I tried with multiple different browsers and packages.
Chrome, Drissionpage, Firefox.
But I always get the same error
Error Message
I have found some older solutions here on stack overflow, that seemed to work in the past, but are not working any more.
The latest that I tried was a Useragent with Firefox and the Gecko.
Here is my code:
import time
import json
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import geckodriver_autoinstaller

# Automatically install the correct version of GeckoDriver
geckodriver_autoinstaller.install()

# Path to Firefox Profile
FIREFOX_PROFILE_PATH = r"C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jqmv3k44.default-release" 

options = Options()
options.add_argument(f"-profile {FIREFOX_PROFILE_PATH}")
options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
options.set_preference("useAutomationExtension", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

# Path to save cookies
COOKIE_FILE = "gmail_cookies.json"

def save_cookies(driver, file_path):
    """Save cookies to a file."""
    with open(file_path, "w") as file:
        json.dump(driver.get_cookies(), file)
    print("Cookies saved successfully.")

def load_cookies(driver, file_path):
    """Load cookies from a file."""
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, "r") as file:
            cookies = json.load(file)
            for cookie in cookies:
                driver.add_cookie(cookie)
        print("Cookies loaded successfully.")
    else:
        print("No cookies file found.")

def is_gmail_logged_in():
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))  # Look for the Gmail search box
        )
        print("Login worked.")
        return True
    except Exception:
        print("Didn't work.")
        return False

# Main script
try:
    # Open Gmail
    driver.get("https://mail.google.com/")

    # Load cookies if available
    load_cookies(driver, COOKIE_FILE)
    driver.refresh()

    # Check if logged in
    if not is_gmail_logged_in():
        print("Log in now")
        input("Press Enter after you have logged in manually and can see your inbox...")
        save_cookies(driver, COOKIE_FILE)
    else:
        print("Already logged in to Gmail.")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

finally:
    driver.quit()

What can I do to solve this problem? I prefer to use chrome but the issue persists either way.

Never post logs, code, input/output samples as images; it's considered a bad practice.

Google has pretty good bot detection for logging in to google accounts.  You'll probably need a robot-like framework running at the OS level.

Thanks, found the solution. Wasn't as deep as a framework running at os level at all
